# How to invoke drawRect: when layoutSubviews invokes in ios

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, layoutsubviews

I am using `drawRect:` to draw shapes. I have to invoke this method and redraw the shapes when orientation changes, so i thought if there is a way to invoke `drawRect:` automatically when `layoutSubviews()` been called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the view's [`contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode) to `.redraw`.

This will invoke `setNeedsDisplay` (and therefore `drawRect`) whenever the view's bounds change, and will therefore also be invoked upon rotation (provided you've setup your [`autoresizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask) so that the view's bounds change on rotation).

Comment: If i set `contentMode` in `init:` it is not working, should i set it in any other method instead?

Comment: @SunilRao Is your `init` getting called (set a breakpoint)? Most of the time in a `UIView` subclass you should be overriding `initWithFrame:` instead of `init` – as the `UIView` implementation of `init` just calls `initWithFrame:CGRectZero`. Also check your `autoresizingMask` to make sure it changes the view's bounds (width or height) on rotation. And no, you should be setting `contentMode` in an initialiser as it's a constant, one-time setup thing.

Answer (score 2):

From the UIView class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event
>   occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should never
>   call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view,
>   and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the setNeedsDisplay or
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: method instead.

That's it. Just call `setNeedsDisplay` on the appropriate view.

Comment: When i call `setNeedsDisplay` from `drawRect:` I am getting this warning **_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)** and **_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)**

Comment: Well as it says that this causes `drawRect:` to be called that would obviously cause an infinite loop. I thought you wanted to call it from `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Oh! yea, what if it is called from `layoutSubviews()` my bad, typos!

Comment: is it ok to be call `setNeedsDisplay` from `layoutSubviews ` ? and i am getting the same error of the above in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad() function put:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and then add the following function:

```
func rotated()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {            
        print("landscape")
        // Your drawRect function here
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        print("Portrait")
        // Your drawRect function here

    }

}
```